# How can I change a field with numbers and letters to just numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Keep up the good work..so far u had helped me with everything that i needed so i hope u can do it once more.

I have a csv file with 7-8 columns and in one specific.

"Cabin" is the name of it has values that varies from A-T but with numbers (not in all of them).

IE A,A23,A43,B,B34 ,B45 etc...

And I want to remake that column into (A,B,C,D,E...etc)..

Any idea how to do it python?

```
for dataset in full_set:
dataset.loc[ dataset['Cabin'] = 'NOCABIN','Cabin']=0
dataset.loc[ dataset['Cabin'] < 'B', 'Cabin']=1 
dataset.loc[(dataset['Cabin'] >= 'B') & (dataset['Cabin'] < 'C'), 'Cabin'] = 2
dataset.loc[(dataset['Cabin'] >= 'C') & (dataset['Cabin'] < 'D'), 'Cabin'] = 3
```

Comment: So, you want to extract the alphabets from cabin codes ?

Comment: In a way yes...its letter is a deck...so c23 means c deck 23 room...and i want to just keep the c deck and delete the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings) to extract the string at a given position.

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'codes': ['A','A23','A43','B','B34' ,'B45','E33']})

## extract code
df['new_codes'] = df['codes'].str.get(0)

print(df)

  codes new_codes
0     A         A
1   A23         A
2   A43         A
3     B         B
4   B34         B
5   B45         B
6   E33         E
```

Comment: I will try that when i get home..thanka for your time